# How to upload more than 1000 entries using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to import an csv file to my database table, the origin of this file was a previous database with the same structure. My issue is that it imports only 1000 rows instead of the whole 62k+ file. The script i'm using is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/covid19.csv'
INTO TABLE covid19.covid19
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id,date,iso2,iso3,country,continent,cases,deaths,population);
```

Comment: Execute this query in CLI. Execute `SHOW WARNINGS;` immediately after and provide the output. If 1000 rows are imported then investigate 1002th row in some text editor for the format correctness. Also check max packet size.

Comment: @Akina The script executes on MySql Shell without warnings, "SHOW WARNINGS;" returns "Empty set". There is no issue in the csv file either, i've deleted the entires from 999 to 1004 and it still imports 1000 entries only. Edit: The size of csv is 3Mb, from what i've seen mysql 8.0 has max packet size of 1Gb

Comment: some clients have an automartiv 1000 rows limit on SELECTs, so make a SELECT CONT(*) FROM covid19.covid19 and see how many rowsd are really there

Comment: @nbk THATS IT! My previous MySQL installation showed every record, but this freshly installed version shows only 1000 rows for some reason.

Comment: @nbk Can you post it as answer so i can accept it and close the question please ?

Comment: ??? You tell that "My issue is that **it imports** only 1000 rows instead of the whole 62k+ file." Not "**selects** 1000 rows after importing". Moreover, you have tried to import via CLI - and you couldn`t not see "62000 records affected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clients have a option, where they reduce the number of returned Rows with a `LIMIT 1000`.

You should check, how many rows you actually have with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM covid19.covid19;
```

You should see the actual number of inserted rows, as the command didn't show any warnungs or errors.